# How can I pass through all but one (not first/last) command line argument, w/o losing quoting?

Tags: bash

I have a script called as:

```
myscript "first argument" "second argument" "third argument" ...
```

I want to call a function from that script as:

```
anotherFunction "first argument" "third argument" ...
```

I'm trying to transform `$@` using `echo`, but the quoting keeps getting lost. My current attempt looks like the following, but it doesn't work; `anotherFunction` gets called with the wrong arguments.

```
delete() {
    commandLine=`echo "$commandLine" | sed "s|$1||"`
}
anotherFunction() {
    echo "Called with first argument:  $1"
    echo "Called with second argument: $2"
}

# shown as a function here so it can be copied and pasted to test
# works the same way when it's actually an external script
myscript() {
  commandLine="$@"
  delete $2
  anotherFunction $commandLine
}

myscript "first argument" "second argument" "third argument"
```

The output I **want** this to have is:

```
Called with first argument:  first argument
Called with second argument: third argument
```

...but instead it's emitting:

```
Called with first argument:  first
Called with second argument: argument
```

Comment: We need to see your code and some sample input and output. Give us a [mcve].

Comment: Using bash to process such string is painful, you could consider use python to process.

Comment: My money is on you not quoting properly and seeing the effects of word splitting, but yes, you need to show the exact commands you're using.

Comment: ...that said, you really, *really*, **really** shouldn't operate on bash commands as strings (except in NUL-delimited form). See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: As soon as you ran `commandLine="$@"`, you'd destroyed your data. You're putting an *array* into a *string*. Strings are, inherently, less expressive than arrays.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I tried to to the same idea with an array but it was'nt working either, can you tell me where is my mistake:
    commands=( $@ )
    for i in ${commands[@]}                                                                                                
    do                                                                                                                     
            echo "string=$i"                                                                                               
    done
shows me :
 string=foo
 string=bar
 string=hello
 string=bar

Comment: The principal mistake there is that you're leaving out the quotes. `$@` and `"$@"` are completely different things. Same for `${commands[@]}` and `"${commands[@]}"`.

Comment: That's true for `$2` and `"$2"` as well. **Always** quote expansions unless you have a specific and compelling reason to want both string-splitting and glob-expansion to take place on contents.

Comment: ...btw, http://shellcheck.net/ would have alerted you to many of these issues without needing to get humans involved.

Comment: As an aside, by the way -- using a `.sh` extension is bad form. It falsely implies that your script can be run with `/bin/sh` (which it can't, if it's a bash script), and means that if you ever rewrite in a different language, you'll either need to change all the script's callers to use a new name reflecting *that* language, or have the language be a complete mismatch for the name. Unless you're defining a shell *library*, just leave the extension off -- executables define commands, and commands on UNIX don't have extensions; you run `ls`, not `ls.elf`.

Comment: I've edited the question to be more clearly asking about what you wanted to do (vs how you were trying to do it).

Comment: ...also added a MCVE, code someone else can copy-and-paste to see the problem themselves, with desired output clearly given as part of the question. Please try to do the same yourself when asking future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to make `myScript "foo" "bar" "hello world"` run `anotherFunction "foo" "hello world"` -- deleting the second argument -- that would look like the following:

```
args=( "$1" "${@:3}" )
anotherFunction "${args[@]}"
```

You could also write it as:

```
args=( "$@" )
unset args[1]
anotherFunction "${args[@]}"
```